# How to replace () and , from the fatched data of mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

I am uploading an image to a directory and inserting the path to 'mysql' database but when i am fetching the path by using

```
sql="""SELECT PATH FROM INAGE"""
cursor.execute(sql)
path=courser.fetchone()
print path
```

it is showing `('/home/pi/image/test.jpeg',)`
i wast to get the output as `'/home/pi/image/test.jpeg'`
how could i replace () and ,

Comment: the `()` and `,` aren't part of the result, they're just decoration around the result. the response is fine

Comment: but when i am using photoimage.open(path). it shows no such file or directory. but photoimage.open('/home/pi/image/test.jpg') works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path,=cursor.fetchone()
print path
```

output will be /home/pi/image/test.jpeg

Answer (score 2):

Your response is wrapped in a tuple. The slickest way to get it out is tuple unpacking:

```
path, =  cursor.fetchone()  # note the comma after path
```

This works because Python has very rudimentary pattern matching for collections.

```
a, b, c, d = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a == 1  # True
b == 2  # True
c == 3  # True
d == 4  # True
```

`cursor.fetchone()` evaluates to a tuple `(1,)` and then you unpack it:

```
path, = (1,) = cursor.fetchone()
```

The other issue here is that parentheses don't actually mean anything -- to the interpreter, `(1,)` is exactly the same as `1,`.